# Указание места хранения файла

Tags: php

С помощью кода ниже сохраняю картинки на хостинге и записываю их имена в БД

```
<?php
include_once('db.php');
if (isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
    $sesion_id = $_SESSION['userid'];
    $idf = ($_SESSION['userid']);

if(isset($_POST['upload'])) {
if(empty($_FILES['file']['size']))  die('Вы не выбрали файл');
if($_FILES['file']['size'] > (5 * 1024 * 1024)) die('image size <5mb');
$imageinfo = getimagesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
$arr = array('image/jpeg','image/gif','image/png');
if(!in_array($imageinfo['mime'],$arr)) echo ('image format');
 else {

$upload_dir = '/public_html/img/avatars'; 

$name = date('YmdHis').basename($_FILES['file']['name']);

$mov = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$name);
  if($mov) {

$name = stripslashes(strip_tags(trim($name)));
 if(!$mysqli->query("UPDATE user SET IMAGE='$upload_dir.$name' WHERE id='".$idf."'")) {echo $mysql->error;}else{};
  }
  else echo 'Error';
 }
}
}
else echo "Session not found";
?>
```

но переменная  `$upload_dir` мною неправильно используется(все картинки все равно грузятся в папку */public_html/*. Как мне сделать так, чтобы картинки загружались именно в папку *avatars*?

Comment: А нельзя ли озвучить сразу все вопросы? или может проще взять готовую CMS? ну или нанять человека... Все вопросы которые вы задавали за вчера\сегодня - находятся на первых строках поиска в гугле.

**$upload_dir = './img/avatars/';**

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков все равно грузит в public

Comment: а вы вернули на родину вот эту строку? как было изначально?
**$name = date('YmdHis').basename($_FILES['file']['name']);**
В ответе ниже вам написали готовый код =)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вместо

```
$upload_dir = '/public_html/img/avatars'; 
$name = date('YmdHis').basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
```

написать так

```
$upload_dir = './img/avatars'; 
$name = $upload_dir . "/" . date('YmdHis').basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
```